# What is difference between old value and new value in trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql

**What is differen between old value and new value in trigger in *mysql***

Comment: The clue is in the name - is there a reason you ask>

Comment: OLD is a row state before the query (not exists for INSERT), NEW is current state of the row (not exists for DELETE), i.e. the state of the row after the query if no further changes will be made on this row in this or further trigger.

Comment: @akina now i understand totally thanks for ur time

Answer (score 1):

If we have a variable called "amount" and for example we use it in a trigger. We will have two variants of that variable ("NEW.amount", "OLD.amount"). These variants refer to the value BEFORE (OLD) and AFTER (NEW) of the trigger. So you can use the different values.
I clarify that in an insert there is no OLD value and that in a delete there is no NEW value.
An example is the following:

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER ins_transaction BEFORE INSERT ON account
   FOR EACH ROW PRECEDES ins_sum
   SET
   @deposits = @deposits + IF(NEW.amount>0,NEW.amount,0),
   @withdrawals = @withdrawals + IF(NEW.amount<0,-NEW.amount,0);
```

More information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: thanks a lot dude well explained thanks for ur precious time

Comment: *An example is the following* ?? What are `@deposits` and `@withdrawals`, where they're initialized? Why you use IF() function whereas the CASE statement usage is obvious? Also CASE decreases the amount of operations twice.

Comment: *We will have two variants of that variable ("NEW.amount", "OLD.amount").* Do not confuse the terms "column" and "variable".